# How can understand if event is sent successfully to consumers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have a main service that publishes event using Spring Stream Kafka and I have 2 different services that consume this event. These services should consume event in order to complete the process.

`Order Service(Publisher-OrderEvent) -- Stock Service(Listener-OrderEvent) -- Payment Service(Listener-OrderEvent)`

(Stock check and payment should completed to complete the order)

How can understand if this event is sent successfully to these two services from order service?
I need to know if one of them is down or not. If it is down/one of the service cannot receieved the event I need to cancel order in order service.
Do you guys have any example implementation for this case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's time to learn about "eventual consistency".

Comment: I am ok if that server gets the event when it is up again, but it is not getting old/unprocessed events either.. waiting for the new event

Comment: Then your server's subscription to the topic is misconfigured.

Comment: Could you please share example of implementation

Answer (score 0):

> Option 1: With metrics & `records-consumed-total`

From the consumer side, monitor this attribute/`metric with the client id` :

```
kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id="{client-id}"
```

Look inside the `records-consumed-total` attribute it will increase once received.

---

> Option 2: With **callback**

You can also use the [call back](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback-) to verify it was sent

"...*Fully non-blocking usage can make use of the Callback parameter to provide a callback that will be invoked **when the request is complete**.*"

```
 ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]>("the-topic", key, value);
 producer.send(myRecord,
               new Callback() {
                   public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
                       if(e != null) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                       } else {
                          //... your code message was received!!
                          System.out.println("The offset of the record we just sent is: " + metadata.offset());
                       }
                   }
               });
```

Comment: Option 2 doesn't guarantee any consumer read it. Option 3 - consumer group lag monitoring